# Rails Auto Complete with typeahed and modal page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, autocomplete, bootstrap-modal

I am working on a rails application and I have implemented autocomplete using twitter's typeahead. Now, when I take the same line say:

```
  <%= f.text_field :name, class: ' load_suggestions form-control', placeholder: "Type  
       Here" %>
```

and use it inside a modal, the javascript file is not being fired. Is there anything that I have to do differently with modals? Thanks.

Comment: how are you calling it by js? Can you post js code?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the reply. Few minutes after I posted it I removed a line that requires bootstrap-modal in application.js (I had both bootstrap and bootstrap-modal required in application.js) and suddenly it worked. But I still don't know why :-)  Thanks anyways.

Comment: no issues voting for this one to close then